# WSO2 IS with SimpleSaml as Identity Provider

Tags: single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

We would like to implement such additional configuration for SSO in our organization:

```
Web application (with SpringSaml) --- WSO2 IS 5.0.0 --- SimpleSaml as IDP for WSO2 IS.
```

Our working SSO configuration is:

```
Other Services --> SimpleSaml
```

Almost all works OK. But if I login to WSO2 IS from my application and from other service I login to SimpleSaml and that other service send LogoutRequest to SimpleSaml, WSO2 IS receive LogoutRequest from SimpleSaml but don't answer and WSO2 IS produces error:

```
    ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Context does not exist. Probably due to invalidated cache
```

I think, it is due to absence of sessionDataKey parameter in the logout request from SimpleSaml.
In IDP metadata for SimpleSaml I set a SingleLogoutService as

```
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://<server>:9443/commonauth"/>
```

Maybe it is not right URL. But I don't find SingleLogout URL for our configuration. 
Could somebody help to resolve this problem or it is not possible to use WSO2 IS in such configuration?
Many thanks in advance!for

P.S. I'm very sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your comments that you have the setup of  SimpleSamlPHP as your IDP which has connected to multiple SPs.Even the SimpleSamlPHP connected to WSO2 IS too.One of the SP send the Logout request to your SimpleSAMLPHP and the SimpleSAMLPHP pass the Logout request to WSO2 IS.

Let me describe how the logout request works on SP initiated Logout request.

1. LogoutRequest issued by SP to  IDP
2. IDP determines authenticated SPs for given user session.  If there are no SPs, other than the SP who sends logout request, the profile proceeds with step 5. Otherwise, steps 3 and 4 are repeated for each SP
3. LogoutRequest issued by IDP to SP
4. SP issues LogoutResponse to IDP
5. IDP issues LogoutResponse to SP who sends logout request.

The Logout URL you can make your custom URL where you want the user to redirect.

Refer the below Url to configure the external IDP to WSO2 IDP.

http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.com/2014/09/leveraging-federation-capabilities-of.html

Comment: Many thanks for Your answer. In our case  when SimpleSaml (IDP) issues logout request to SP (according to my configuration - to WSO2 IS) (this is spep 3), it does not get answer - LogoutResponse (step 4), because LogoutRequest dont have any information about session in WSO2 IS. I think You suggested to set logout URL in SimpleSaml to url in my web application, but in this case what about service in WSO2 IS? If I issue logout request from my web application (service) to WSO2 IS, all works OK:  thru WSO2 IS to IDP (SimpleSaml), there logout other SPs and back -> WSO2 IS ->. Web App

Answer (score 0):

If you are using /samlsso end point in WSO2IS, It means that your are using SAML2 SSO. Therefore, you must send a proper logout request to the /samlsso end point. If you need to get more idea about SSO logout with SAML2 SSO, Please go through the below URL.

http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/06/28/how-saml2-single-logout-works/